# Can't change company coq mode map

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

I installed a minor mode for coq-mode, called company coq. It binds the `<menu>` key to `company-coq-toggle-definition-overlay` here:

```
(defconst company-coq--core-map
  (let ((cc-map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key cc-map [remap proof-goto-point] #'company-coq-proof-goto-point)
    cc-map)
  "Keymap for core company-coq keybindings.
Do not edit this keymap: instead, edit `company-coq-map'.")

(defvar company-coq-map
  (let ((cc-map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    ;...
    (define-key cc-map (kbd "<menu>") #'company-coq-toggle-definition-overlay)
    cc-map)
  "Keymap of company-coq keybindings.
These keybindings are activated by `company-coq--keybindings-minor-mode'.")

(define-minor-mode company-coq--keybindings-minor-mode
  "Minor mode providing convenient company-coq keybindings."
  :lighter nil
      :keymap company-coq-map)
```

It says: Do not edit this keymap: instead, edit `company-coq-map'

But no matter how I try to edit `company-coq-map`, I still can't change it. I tried this:

```
(defun my-company-coq ()
      (local-set-key (kbd "<menu>") 'kill-ring-save)
      )

(eval-after-load 'company-coq-mode
      '(define-key company-coq-map [(menu)] 'kill-ring-save))

(add-hook 'cc-mode-hook 'my-company-coq)
```

How to reset this key to kill-ring-save?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by this:

```
(defun my-company-coq ()
      (define-key company-coq-map (kbd "<menu>") #'kill-ring-save)
      )

(add-hook 'company-coq-mode-hook 'my-company-coq)
```